# Django Can't open Admin page (Url Change and get message)

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am getting a message while trying to page Admin.

This is default url page
[image]

I change url to this
[image]

When I click enter , url was change and get message

[image]

How to fix this?

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: post your urls.py please

Comment: @MaranSowthri ok update now

Comment: What is your base url?

Comment: What is base url ? Do you mean path url ? @Seb

Comment: I mean the url you must have defined in your settings, because all your paths will be based on it. In your case it seems that you have defined your base url as ```https://kongdev.testapp.com/test/admintest/devtes```.

Comment: in settings.py i set  "ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['kongdev.testapp.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']"  Is base url ? @Seb

Comment: Did you add 'django.contrib.admin' in your `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple?  If yes then maybe try to run python `manage.py syncdb`. Otherwise in which urls.py have you declared this path, the app's one or your project's one?